# Wrong overloaded call using generic interfaces

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

suppose i have this definitions:

```
TMyClass1 = class
end;

TMyClass2 = class
end;

IModel<T : class> = interface
  ['{E8262D6C-DCAB-46AC-822E-EC369CF734F8}']
  function List() : TObjectList<T>;
end;

IPresenter<T : class> = interface
  ['{98FB7751-D75A-4C51-B55A-0E5FE68BE213}']
  function Retrieve() : TObjectList<T>;
end;

IView<T : class> = interface
  ['{59384CD6-30D6-4BD8-AB3D-7FCF4D1A8618}']
  procedure AssignPresenter(APresenter : IPresenter<T>);
end;

TModel<T : class> = class(TInterfacedObject, IModel<T>)
public
  function List() : TObjectList<T>; virtual; abstract;
end;

TPresenter<T : class> = class(TInterfacedObject, IPresenter<T>)
strict private
  { Private declarations }
  FModel : IModel<T>;
  FView : IView<T>;
public
  constructor Create(AView : IView<T>);
  function Retrieve() : TObjectList<T>; virtual; abstract;
end;

TModelClass1 = class(TModel<TMyClass1>);

TPresenterClass1 = class(TPresenter<TMyClass1>);

TModelClass2 = class(TModel<TMyClass2>);

TPresenterClass2 = class(TPresenter<TMyClass2>);
```

and i have this form that implements some of the things i defined:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm, IView<TMyClass1>, IView<TMyClass2>)
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
private
  { Private declarations }
  FPresenter1 : IPresenter<TMyClass1>;
  FPresenter2 : IPresenter<TMyClass2>;
  procedure AssignPresenter(APresenter : IPresenter<TMyClass1>); overload;
  procedure AssignPresenter(APresenter : IPresenter<TMyClass2>); overload;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TPresenterClass1.Create((Self as IView<TMyClass1>));
 TPresenterClass2.Create((Self as IView<TMyClass2>));
end;

procedure TForm1.AssignPresenter(APresenter: IPresenter<TMyClass1>);
begin
  Self.FPresenter1 := APresenter;
end;

procedure TForm1.AssignPresenter(APresenter: IPresenter<TMyClass2>);
begin
  Self.FPresenter2 := APresenter;
end;
```

so the problem here is that delphi can't figure out what method to call, in this example, only the `AssignPresenter(APresenter: IPresenter<TMyClass2>)` is called in both cases, so probably im missing something here but i can't figure out atm.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate but I cannot find it right now.

The problem is that the `as` operator for interfaces is not very compatible with generics. The `as` operator relies on the interface GUID. The interface is found by querying for an interface with matching GUID. And GUIDs don't fit at all well with generic instantiation.

Now let's look at your code.

```
TPresenterClass1.Create((Self as IView<TMyClass1>));
TPresenterClass2.Create((Self as IView<TMyClass2>));
```

The problem is that `IView<TMyClass1>` and `IView<TMyClass2>` have the same GUID:

```
type
  IView<T : class> = interface
    ['{59384CD6-30D6-4BD8-AB3D-7FCF4D1A8618}']
    procedure AssignPresenter(APresenter : IPresenter<T>);
  end;
```

So both `IView<TMyClass1>` and `IView<TMyClass2>` share the same GUID, and when you query using `as`, the same interface will be returned irrespective of whether or not you asked for `IView<TMyClass1>` or `IView<TMyClass2>`.

So, the bottom line here is that `as` is rendered next to useless with generic interfaces as soon as an object implements `ISomeInterface<T>` twice with different `T`.

Embarcadero really should implement `as` in a manner that supports generics. I wouldn't hold your breath though.

You will need to find a different way to solve your problem.

Comment: @EProgrammer I found that one but it's a little different. It's about there being no GUID. This one's about generic instantiations and GUIDs.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `as` when you have the object implementing the interface - just write:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TPresenterClass1.Create(Self);
  TPresenterClass2.Create(Self);
end;
```

The compiler figures this out properly. When you are using `as` it does a `Supports` call which fails for the reason explained by David already.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to David Heffernan's answer.

One way you could work around the problem would be to give a unique GUID to all the generic declarations you use:

```
IViewMyclass1 = interface(IView<TMyClass1>)
['{1A0F941F-BAB1-4723-A6C1-27036DF5D344}']
end;

IViewMyclass2 = interface(IView<TMyClass2>)
['{0C61A23A-DC50-43B0-97C9-8B0013DDC193}']
end;
```

Redefine the view's declaration.

```
TForm4 = class(TForm, IViewMyclass1, IViewMyclass2)

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TPresenterClass1.Create((Self as IViewMyclass1));
 TPresenterClass2.Create((Self as IViewMyclass2));
end;
```

And then the right overload is called.

Disclaimers:

- This is the result of On-The-Fly testing (XE4). Reliability is unknown.
- I'm aware this isn't very practical.
- It's probably not something that should be extensively used as it isn't obvious where the code would fail.